# Spring MVC-binding multiple object by model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I got a problem when I use @ModelAttribute

there always got value from different field  and set the one class property
here is code

```
    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String form(Model theModel){
        theModel.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        theModel.addAttribute("teacher", new Teacher());
        theModel.addAttribute("countries", countries);
        theModel.addAttribute("language", language);

        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/student")
    public String showStudent(
            @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
            @ModelAttribute("teacher") Teacher teacher,
                              Model theModel)
    {
        System.out.println(student.getName());
        System.out.println(teacher.getName());
        theModel.addAttribute("student",student);
        theModel.addAttribute("teacher",teacher);
        return "student";
    }`
```

```
<body>
<h1>EnterInfo</h1>
<form th:action="@{/student}"  method="post">
    <p>student info</p>
  <label for="name">StudentName：</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" th:field="*{student.name}" required="required" />
<!--                                       Student.setName-->
  <br />

  <label for="age">StudentAge：</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" th:field="*{student.age}" required="required" />
  <br />

    StudentCountry :
    <select th:field="*{student.country}">
<!--                             Student.setCountry-->
    <option th:each="tempCountry : ${countries}" th:value="${tempCountry}" th:text="${tempCountry}"></option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <label>StudentLanguage：</label>
    <input th:field="*{student.language}" type="radio"
           th:each="tempLang : ${language}" th:value="${tempLang}" th:text="${tempLang}" >
    <br>

    <label>StudentSkills：</label>
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{student.Skill}" value="Java" /> Java
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{student.Skill}" value="Python" /> Python
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{student.Skill}" value="C++" /> C++
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>teacher info</p>
    <label for="tname">TeacherName：</label>
    <input type="text" id="tname" th:field="*{teacher.name}" required="required" />

    <br />
    <label for="tage">TeacherAge：</label>
    <input type="number" id="tage" th:field="*{teacher.age}" required="required" />
    <br />
    TeacherCountry :
    <select th:field="*{teacher.country}">
        <option th:each="tempCountry : ${countries}" th:value="${tempCountry}" th:text="${tempCountry}"></option>
    </select>
<br>
    <label>StudentLanguage：</label>
    <input th:field="*{teacher.language}" type="radio"
           th:each="tempLang : ${language}" th:value="${tempLang}" th:text="${tempLang}" >
    <br>

    <label>StudentSkills：</label>
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{teacher.Skill}" value="Java" /> Java
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{teacher.Skill}" value="Python" /> Python
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{teacher.Skill}" value="C++" /> C++
    <br>

    <label for="tsub">TeacherSubject：</label>
    <input type="text" id="tsub" th:field="*{teacher.subject}" required="required" />

    <br>
  <input type="submit" value="提交" />
</form>
</body>
```

here is result

```
<h1>result 1</h1>
<p>S_name: <span th:text="${student.name}"></span></p>
<p>S_age: <span th:text="${student.age}"></span></p>
<p>S_country: <span th:text="${student.country}"></span></p>
<p>S_lang: <span th:text="${student.language}"></span></p>
<p>S_skills: <span th:each="skill: ${student.Skill}"   th:text="${skill+' '} "></span></p>


<h1>result 2</h1>
<p>t_name: <span th:text="${teacher.name}"></span></p>
<p>t_age: <span th:text="${teacher.age}"></span></p>
<p>t_country: <span th:text="${teacher.country}"></span></p>
<p>t_lang: <span th:text="${teacher.language}"></span></p>
<p>t_skills: <span th:each="skill: ${teacher.Skill}"   th:text="${skill+' '} "></span></p>
<p>t_sub: <span th:text="${teacher.subject}"></span></p>
```

as the pic They all have all the information from different input I entered, rather than each of them individually
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKRa8.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqtvb.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sNgo.png)

I try many time and ask gpt but still confused and did not resolve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.